# Mouseover effect on full stretch button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using a WPF button mouse ovent to show a specific area in screen and i use the below xaml in code

http://pastebin.com/Rn0CVAHA.

If i remove the Background="Red" property of button control i have to click on exactly the center to show my area on screen .
The screen shot is [image]

How can i make the button control in a way that it works without background color ,but stretch content effect ? Like clicking anywhere on the button area should show the content

Comment: Did you try setting the background color to Transparent?

Comment: @Krishna, you have correctly determined the solution. Please add that (hopefully with some further information) into an answer so that this question may be marked as answered. Thanks.

Comment: Yes i am trying it with a transparent button .But is any way to make it content as stretch ?

Comment: In [tag:wpf] mouse events are only applicable to non-empty client region (non-transparent). You could use a simple trick - put something opaque to accept mouse events *behind* that what will be transparent.

Comment: Can u help me to edit the similar stuff ? I want to show the contents behind this BUton control [ Or button is on top of a browser control]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that this is the offending line in your code

```
<Border Name="border" Background="Red">
      <ContentPresenter  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Border>
```

The problem is, when you remove the background of the border there is no hittest on the border to react the mouse triggers (IsMouseOver in your case)

The trick is to set the background brush to transparent so that the background can be hit test and will respond to your triggers.

so try changing your Border to

```
<Border Name="border" Background="Transparent">
          <ContentPresenter  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Border>
```

You can read more about Hit testing on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx)

Comment: Transparent color will not work. I am pretty sure (but not 100%, therefore no downvoting).

Comment: I tried a lot to make it for whole area without any success . Anyone can help to clear the xaml i posted

Comment: @JMat Sorry I do not understand the problem. When I Changed the background brush of the border from red to Transparent then I can still mouseover any part of the button for your storyboard to run? Can you provide more details of your problem please?