# How to make the Button to react whole area on hover

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-style

I've got custom button template. Button contains canvas element, canvas contains two lines (cross).

What I want to achieve is to change background colour of button when mouse is over the button.
However, background is changing now only when mouse is over canvas line element which is small part of whole area of button.

Could you please tell me what I can do to make changing background when mouse is over any area of the button?

I can see in XAML editor that Canvas element is stretched on whole button but it still doesn't work until mouse is over line element.

This is my button style:

```
<Style x:Key="TitleButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Padding"          Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"  Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"      Value="Gray" />
    <Setter Property="Width"            Value="{StaticResource TitleButtonWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="Background"       Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border Name="border">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="LightSlateGray"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

And my button:

```
<Button x:Name="CloseButton" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Style="{StaticResource TitleButton}" Click="CloseButton_Click" >
    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Line X1="15" X2="25" Y1="20" Y2="10" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black"></Line>
        <Line X1="15" X2="25" Y1="10" Y2="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black"></Line>
    </Canvas>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this thread: [Mouseover effect on full stretch button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234526/mouseover-effect-on-full-stretch-button)

What I had to do is just add transparent border background.

```
<Border Name="border" Background="Transparent">
     <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
         <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
     </Grid>
</Border>
```

So simple!